# HttpErrorResponse in angular is not behaving as an object

Tags: c#, angular, http, web-services, error-handling

I have a call to a service in angular like

```
  removeFromAttended(class: CLS_Class) {
    this.svcSubscriptions.deleteByStudenteAndClass(class.id , this.studentID).subscribe({
      next: res=> { ...do things... },
      error: (err: HttpErrorResponse) => { console.log("I get:", err) }
    })
  }
```

It's a delete of a record in a database and it works perfectly.

Being this a delete it happens that sometimes it's not possible to perform, due to the fact that in another table there might be records related to the one I want to remove.

I have then refactored my webservice which, when it detects there are related records in a certain table, returns an error message like "there are correlated records in table xy" and returns a BadRequest...
Just for the sake of completeness in C# there is this passage

```
if (relatedPagelle.Any())
       {
            // Return a message to indicate related records
            return BadRequest("Esistono pagelle per questa iscrizione. Impossibile eliminare.");
        }
```

It works fine in the SWAGGER from Visual Studio in C#, returning the desired message.

I then published the webservice.
I call the service and, when I try to delete a record which has related records in another table, it correctly returns an error.

Now the problem:
From the Chrome Inspect Console I ACTUALLY CAN SEE THE MESSAGE: **it arrives indeed in the network/Response window** (see screenshot), but I can't figure out how to get it from Angular.

I tried EVERY property of err, like err.message, err.status, err.headers, err.type, err.name ...ALL of them return **undefined**, while if I write simply err (like above) it returns BadRequest as if err was a string and not an object....

But shouldn't it be an HttpErrorResponse object which includes a number of properties among which the message too? Why is it appearing in the Chrome Console from the network window and it's not accessible from the code?
Thanks[image: here the screenshot of the network window which shows the message arrives to the browser]

Comment: Purely a side note: 400 Bad Request is for invalid inputs. The inputs are not invalid in this case. Rather, the state of the data on the server is such that the operation cannot be completed. Thus, a 409 Conflict should be returned instead.

Comment: *"shouldn't it be an HttpErrorResponse object which includes a number of properties among which the message too"* - The `error` handler is for communication errors, like not being able to connect. The `next` handler is for any successful *communication*, even if the response code is an error. At least, that's my guess, as I assume this communication is backed by the Fetch API.

Comment: Can you share the code implementation for `deleteByStudenteAndClass` method?

Comment: Remember: "the services return Observables, we subscribe in components". Unless your service dispatch a Subject and you subscribe to this subject remember that in Angular we "see" the components, so all the visual part are in this components, not in service.

Comment: @YongShun This is the service I call

  deleteByStudenteAndClass(classID: number, studentID: number): Observable <any>{
    return this.http.delete( environment.apiBaseUrl  + 'CLS_Iscrizioni/DeleteByAlunnoAndClasseSezioneAnno/'+alunnoID+'/'+classeSezioneAnnoID);

Comment: @madreflection are you sure? I am getting the error through the error handler not through the next handler.....

Comment: I try to mock the `HttpErrorResponse` observable and able to get all info for `err`. Something weird. Otherwise you may try to place a `catchError` rxjs operator in the observable to check the response value received.

Comment: I tried that too:
  deleteByStudenteAndClass(..arguments): Observable <any>{
    return this.http.delete( environment.apiBaseUrl  + '..path'+studentID+'/'+classID);

    .pipe(
      catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.error(err.error, err.headers, err.message, err.name, err.ok, err.status);
        return err.message
      })
    )
__________
 BUT still it is going through the error handler and not the next handler.
AND in this case the console.log("I get:", err)returns

TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. ...

Answer (score 0):

I have found what was wrong.
I had an httpErrorInterceptor that messed up all errors, and sort of flattened them.

I didn't remember I had created such a middle step for all calls.
Removing it solved the thing.
Now err is gone back to be an object with properties like I expected.